# How to implement Red hat Process Automation Manager(RHPAM) with NodeJs

Tags: node.js, jbpm, bpmn

I am new to Business process automation, trying to implement using Red hat process automation manager for my Node.js application.

Please help me out with the process or if there is any source code available for Node.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the REST API which you can find swagger documentation for running on the server. For example `http://localhost:8080/kie-server/docs`. You will have to create a process and deploy it and then control it from your application.

I don't have a javascript example but I have in Java an example for the common `Evaluation` process example that the jBPM team uses. Maybe this helps.

```
private void runjBPMApi() throws IOException {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("content-type", "application/json");
    headers.add("accept", "application/json");

    HttpHeaders headersMary = new HttpHeaders();
    headersMary.addAll(headers);
    headersMary.add("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode("mary:mary".getBytes())));

    HttpHeaders headersJack = new HttpHeaders();
    headersJack.addAll(headers);
    headersJack.add("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode("jack:jack".getBytes())));        

    HttpHeaders headersJohn = new HttpHeaders();
    headersJohn.addAll(headers);
    headersJohn.add("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode("john:john".getBytes())));        

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 

    String startEval = "{\"employee\":\"jack\"}";
    HttpEntity<String> requestEval = new HttpEntity<>(startEval, headersMary); 
    ResponseEntity<String> evaluation = 
        restTemplate.exchange(serverRestUrl+"/containers/"+containerId+"/processes/Evaluation.Evaluation/instances",
            HttpMethod.POST, 
            requestEval, String.class );

    Long processId = Long.parseLong( evaluation.getBody() );
    log.info("Started Process Instance: " + processId.toString());

    String selfEval = "{\"selfeval\":\"did lots of work\"}";
    performUserTaskApi(restTemplate, headersJack, selfEval, false, mapper);
    String pmEval = "{\"pmeval\":\"Projects Done\"}";
    performUserTaskApi(restTemplate, headersJohn, pmEval, true, mapper);
    String hrEval = "{\"hreval\":\"No Incidents\"}";
    performUserTaskApi(restTemplate, headersMary, hrEval, true, mapper);

    HttpEntity<String> requestVariables = new HttpEntity<>(headersMary);
    ResponseEntity<String> variables = 
        restTemplate.exchange(serverRestUrl+"/containers/"+containerId+"/processes/instances/"+processId+"/variables/instances",
            HttpMethod.GET, 
            requestVariables, String.class );
    JsonNode variableTree = mapper.readTree(variables.getBody());
    Iterator<JsonNode> variablesItr = variableTree.findValue("variable-instance").elements();
    while ( variablesItr.hasNext() ) {
        log.info( variablesItr.next().toString() );
    }
}

private void performUserTaskApi(RestTemplate restTemplate, HttpHeaders userHeaders, String params, boolean claim, ObjectMapper mapper) throws IOException {
    HttpEntity<String> emptyEntity = new HttpEntity<>(userHeaders);
    HttpEntity<String> paramsEntity = new HttpEntity<>(params, userHeaders);
    ResponseEntity<String> potOwners = 
        restTemplate.exchange(serverRestUrl+"/queries/tasks/instances/pot-owners",
            HttpMethod.GET, emptyEntity, String.class );

    JsonNode evalTree = mapper.readTree(potOwners.getBody());
    Long taskId = evalTree.findValue("task-id").asLong();

    if ( claim ) {
        restTemplate.exchange(serverRestUrl+"/containers/"+containerId+"/tasks/"+taskId+"/states/claimed",
            HttpMethod.PUT, emptyEntity, String.class );
    }
    restTemplate.exchange(serverRestUrl+"/containers/"+containerId+"/tasks/"+taskId+"/states/started",
        HttpMethod.PUT, emptyEntity, String.class );

    restTemplate.exchange(serverRestUrl+"/containers/"+containerId+"/tasks/"+taskId+"/states/completed",
        HttpMethod.PUT, paramsEntity, String.class );

}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. So, my understanding is, use REST task and configure the REST task URL to connect to my Node.js application to control the functionalities?

Comment: Perhaps I would say that you configure the Node.js application to connect to the jBPM REST interface and control the process. It's not really clear what you are asking. If you want the process to connect to an external program you would probably use a REST workitem. Since you are new it's probably better if you read the documentation for a while.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Business Central to model your projects and deploy it on KIE Server (in general you don't need you app here, Business Central abilities should be enough. Or you can create your projects in your preferred IDE and deploy it to KIE Server manually.

Once your project is done and deployed on KIE Server you can use Kie Server API to control your project and it's assets (like business processes). You can write your app to control your projects on KIE Server on any language and technologies like Node.JS or mobile app.

Use link provided by K. Nicholas http://localhost:8080/kie-server/docs to access the docs for REST API of KIE Server.

Below is an example of such an API: [image]

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t matter if your front end application build in NodeJS or any other scripting technologies. You can use rest-api capabilities provided by RHPAM by calling from your frontend application. You can check all the exposed rest APIs via url: http://hostname:port/kie-server/docs mentioned by Nicholas and Kirill in above comments and call the exposed API from front end application.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).